# Bash regexp pattern replacement (while parsing .csv)

Tags: string, bash, csv

Parsing .csv file. It contains some cells with text like:

```
,"Some words, some more words, an so on",
```

So using `,` delimeter doesn't work correctly. The only solution i see is a regex pattern, which matches the string. To replace commas inside `"  "` with some rarely used symbol combination (like '___'). And to replace back to the original after script finish it's job.

Something like `echo ${var//in/out}`

But i'm not strong in regular expressions.
And maybe i don't see more obvious solution.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Parsing a quoted CSV with standard tools is tricky, and when a quoted field contains a literal newline character it's even more difficult. There exists external tools for manipulating CSV files, they can make your life easier; you should try Miller https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or CSVtools https://github.com/DavyLandman/csvtools

Comment: [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-2) defines RFC and says to use quotes if the field contains the separator character, like here the commas. Try to get a csv library, regex is the wrong tool to parse csv.

Comment: You mention `And to replace back to the original after script finish it's job.` - depending on what the job is, it's very likely you don't need to do any replacement at all. Post a new question if you'd like help with whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

For the conversion you're trying to do all you need is:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(/ *, */," ",$i)} 1' file
,"Some words some more words an so on",
```

For anything more interesting see [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for how to use awk on CSVs.

Answer (score -1):

Got the solution by myself.

First replace all сombinations of `,`  to `___` in initial file

`cat ./initial_file.csv | sed -e 's|, |___|g'`

In the end replace back all `___` to initial `,`

`sed -i 's|___|, |g' ./final_file.csv`

Not so tricky :)

Comment: Well, that would work when the commas in your quoted fields are **always** followed by a space **and** there's no other field that starts with a space. No one but you can guess that your CSV satisfy both conditions

Comment: That's clear. I didn't try to solve some common issue, but just a small task.

Comment: That would convert any `___` that exists in the input to ```,<blank>```s